# Stop JS infinite loop execution in webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, infinite-loop

I'm evaluating a simple infinite JS loop in an android app inside webview (`webview.evaludateJavascript(script)`), something like `for(;;){}`. Then I want to stop|interrupt the script execution, but I can't find a way how to do that. It keeps running until I reload the application.

What I tried:

Open a blank page with `webView.loadUrl("about:blank");`

Disable JS with `webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);`

Destroy webview with `webview.destroy()`

nothing mentioned above helps, I still can see CPU cores loaded until I close the app.

Comment: use a while loop? Or have an if condition inside your loop which is false when the webview is destroyed and then use a break statement?

Comment: @lyncx, in the title I mentioned "Infinite loop", would it contain a "break" it wouldn't be infinite and I wouldn't have to ask this question. In other words, I don't have a possibility to change the JS script, I hope it is possible to kill/destroy/terminate the webview thread somehow.